# Ground wires for a 1992 Ford Ranger with a 2.3 engine

Tags: ford, wiring, ranger

I'm changing out my pos and neg cables.

The neg has one ground wire with two eyelets where the bolts go through, one is hooked to the frame but the other I don't know where it goes, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly are you having problems with here? I'm not seeing the question.

Comment: Is the replacement cable identical to the one you removed?

Answer (score 3):

The ground wire will usually run from the battery to the chassis and then onto the engine.

Some vehicles will do this with one single length - which is what yours sounds like and others will have separate ones. So, the engine / gearbox may have a strap at the end of the gearbox across the gearbox rubber mount because it is shorter and cheaper..

A picture would help but this is the most common system. to provide the necessary grounding - starter motors take a lot of current.